# set() runtime in python

Tags: python

Just wondering what the run time of lookup for set() is? O(1) or O(n)?

if I have

x = set()
whats the runtime of

if "a" in x:
print a in set!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`set` is implemented using a hash, so the lookup is, on average, close to O(1). The worst case is O(n), where n objects have colliding hashes.

Comment: Note that the hash functions and collision resolution algorithm are chosen to make the O(n) case much less threatening than it sounds.