# Searching for a sequence in a text

Tags: python

I have run into a logic problem.

I have a string declared as follows:

```
fruits = "banana grapes apple"
vegetables = "potatoes cucumber carrot"
```

Now there are some text sentences, and i have to search for the word that is in front of the text format `<vegetables> <fruits>`

```
I ate carrot grapes ice cream for dessert.
```

Answer : **ate**

```
Dad and mom brought banana cucumber and milk.
```

Answer : **brought**

What i was thinking is to split the sentence and put it in an array, and then look for the sequence, i was able to break the sentence but matching the sequence is a problem.

```
wd = sentence.split(' ')
for x in wd.strip().split():
# now i will have to look for the sequence
```

Now, i will have to look for the text that is in front of the text format

Comment: What's the expected output for :`'banana cucumber and carrot are my favourites.'`?

Comment: I think you mean _behind_ not _in front of_, because in your examples the target word is behind either a vegetable or fruit.

Answer (score 2):

You're using wrong data-structures here, convert fruits and vegetables to sets. Then the problem is very easy to solve:

```
>>> fruits = set("banana grapes apple".split())
>>> vegetables = set("potatoes cucumber carrot".split())
>>> fruits_vegs = fruits | vegetables                  
>>> from string import punctuation
def solve(text):                                   
    spl = text.split()
    #use itertools.izip and iterators for memory efficiency.
    for x, y in zip(spl, spl[1:]): 
        #strip off punctuation marks
        x,y = x.translate(None, punctuation), y.translate(None, punctuation)
        if y in fruits_vegs and x not in fruits_vegs:
            return x
...         
>>> solve('I ate carrot grapes ice cream for dessert.')
'ate'
>>> solve('Dad and mom brought banana cucumber and milk.')
'brought'
>>> solve('banana cucumber and carrot.')
'and'
```

Comment: Using the set data structure also has an additional benefit that sets are implemented in a hashy way, so look-up gets a performance boost (compared to, for example, iterating an array): http://stackoverflow.com/a/2381054/624590

Answer (score 1):

```
fruits = "banana grapes apple".split(" ")
vegetables = "potatoes cucumber carrot".split(" ")

sentence = 'Dad and mom brought banana cucumber and milk.'

wd = sentence.split(' ')
for i, x in enumerate(wd):
    if (x in fruits or x in vegetables) and i > 0:
        print wd[i-1]
        break
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: You're right.  I forgot to group the or expressions.  Now it should work (assuming the expected behavior is to ignore an initial 'banana'.  If the user could clarify what it should return in such a case, I'll edit the answer accordingly.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regex:

```
def to_group(l):
    ''' make a regex group from a list of space-separated strings '''
    return '(?:%s)' % ('|'.join(l.split()))

pattern = r'(\w+) %s %s' % (to_group(vegetables), to_group(fruits))
print re.findall(pattern, string)
```